# Select and Copy a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy all the non-blank records in a column and paste them somewhere.

The code below works fine until I've got a situation where I only have one record, and it would copy the entire column (`A2` to `A1048576`). So when it tried to paste the values to the new area, I have an error because there are not enough rows.

Can someone please help? I am not expecting to see more than 2000 records, I think the real problem here is only the situation when I have just one record and I wanted to copy that record, not the entire column.

```
Sheets("FinalListofContracts").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better to count the last row no and give the range to copy the sheet.
Here is a fucntion that return the number of rows and simply copy according the returned row count.

```
Function RowCounter(sSheetName As String, sRangeCol As String) As Long
   Dim rowCnt As Long
    rowCnt = 0
    Sheets(sSheetName).Select
    rowCnt = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Range(sRangeCol).Column).End(xlUp).Row
    RowCounter = rowCnt
End Function

Sub copyRow()
    Dim aRange As String
     rowCnt = RowCounter("FinalListofContracts", "A1")
     aRange = "A1:A" & rowCnt     
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FinalListofContracts").Range(aRange).copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before expanding the selection to the full range, we can test if that full range would be more than 2000 rows in count. Or rather, we can select the range only if it is fewer than 2000 rows in count. Full code:

```
Sheets("FinalListofContracts").Select
Range("A2").Select
If Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count < 2000 Then
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End If
Selection.Copy
```

Obviously, you could make that 2000 bigger.... anywhere between 2000 (if that's always your maximum) and 65000 (if using old file format) should give the desired result.